# Useing php and ajax to insert data to database

Tags: php, ajax

My problem is my code go to else condition. So what I want I need if condition.
see my code bellow :

Ajax code :

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(function(){
                    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
                        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                        {
                            var my_value = ($(this).val());
                            alert(my_value);
                            var toLoad = "ajax.php/"+my_value;
                            $("#my_div").load(toLoad,function(response,status,xhr){
                                if(status == "error"){
                                    alert("Please check again have some error ");
                                }
                                else{
                                    alert($(this).val());

                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

- Html code:

```
<div id="my_div">

            <form>
                <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water"> yes<br>
                <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Beer"> Good<br>
                <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Wine">Exellent 
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?php
               if(isset($_GET['my_value'])) {
                   echo $_GET['my_value'];
                   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
                   mysql_query("INSERT INTO test_ajax(id, username, password) VALUES(Null,'sothorn', '123')");
               }else
                   echo "Not get value";
            ?>
        </div>
```

I would like to insert database but it go to else condition please help me

Answer (score 0):

var toLoad = "ajax.php/"+my_value;//this line

//should be

var toLoad = "ajax.php/my_value="+my_value;//this code